# yum update does not work (repository problem)

Tags: centos, package-management, yum

```bash
# yum update -y
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Update Process
Determining fastest mirrors
YumRepo Error: All mirror URLs are not using ft, http[s] or file.
Eg. Invalid release/repo/arch combination/
removing mirrorlist with no valid mirrors: /var/cache/yum/×86 64/6/base/mirrorli st.txt
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base [root@localhost Desktop]# cd/etc/yum. repos.d/ bash: cd/etc/yum.repos.d/: No such file or directory [root@localhost Desktop]# cd /etc/yum. repos. d/ [root@localhost yum. repos.d]# ll total 32
- M-Г--г=
- Пу-Г--г-.
1 root root 1991 May 19 2016 CentOS-Base.repo
1 root root 1991 May
9 14:14 Cent0S-base. repo.old
1 root root
647 May 19 2016 CentOs-Debuginfo.repo
1 root root
289 May 19
2016 Cent0S-fasttrack.repo
- M-r--г.
1 root root 630 May 19 2016 CentOS-Media.repo
- [/-Г-- Г-
. 1 root root 6259 May 19
2016 CentOS-Vault. repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 259 Sep 30 2015 virtualbox. repo [root@localhost yum. repos.d]# cp Centos-Base. repo CentOs-Base.repo.old [rootalocalhost yum. repos.d]# ll total 36
- T-T---- . 1 root root 1991 May 19
2016 Cent0S-Base. repo
1 root root 1991 May
9 14:14 CentOS-base.repo.old
- To re
1 root root 1991 May
9 14:22 Centos -Base. repo.old
1 root root
647 May 19 2016 CentOS -Debuginfo.repo
- П-Г-
포
1 root root
289 May 19 2016 CentOS-fasttrack.repo
-rw-r--r--, 1 root root 630 May 19 2016 CentOS-Media. repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 6259 May 19 2016 Cents-Vault. repo
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 259 Sep 30 2015 virtualbox. repo [root@localhost yum. repos.d]# vi CentOs- Base. repo [root@localhost yum. repos.d]# yum clean all
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Error: File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, line: 4
'update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and\n' [root@localhost yum. repos.d]#
```

Comment: Please edit your question to put the actual output into code brackets for readability.

Comment: Thanks for your comment , means a lot to me!!! 
Sir am new comer here , don’t know how to post my question, Means , do I have to write my question within square brackets or have to write the code in which am getting the error. … I uploaded the image or code as well … but don’t know whether it’s visible to you ‍♀️

Answer (score 2):

The file `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` should look like this (example from CentOS 7, your version may be somewhat different but should have a similar structure):

```
# CentOS-Base.repo
#
# The mirror system uses the connecting IP address of the client and the
# update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and
# geographically close to the client.  You should use this for CentOS updates
# unless you are manually picking other mirrors.
#
# If the mirrorlist= does not work for you, as a fall back you can try the 
# remarked out baseurl= line instead.
#
#

[base]
name=CentOS-7 - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=$basearch&repo=os&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#released updates 
[updates]
name=CentOS-7 - Updates
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=$basearch&repo=updates&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/updates/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that may be useful
[extras]
name=CentOS-7 - Extras
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=$basearch&repo=extras&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7

#additional packages that extend functionality of existing packages
[centosplus]
name=CentOS-7 - Plus
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=7&arch=$basearch&repo=centosplus&infra=$infra
#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/centosplus/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
enabled=0
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-7
```

The lines with square brackets (`[base]`, `[updates]`, and `[extras]`) are *section headers*, and each block of settings starting with a section header until the next section header line (or end-of-file) is a *section*. Each section defines one possible repository to download packages from.

If the repository section uses the `mirrorlist=` line, it tells `yum` to first download a list of repository mirror URLs from the specified URL, and then use one of those mirrors. If the section uses the `baseurl=` line, it directly specifies the URL of the package repository.

In a high-security firewalled environment, the `mirrorlist=` lines can cause headaches as the IP addresses of the package repositories the system might connect to cannot be determined in advance, as the mirror list can vary over time, and may include *content delivery networks* such as Akamai, which are located all over the internet. This makes for long and hard-to-manage firewall access lists.

So it is fairly common to comment out the `mirrorlist=` line and instead un-comment the corresponding `baseurl=` line, and possibly even specify a custom repository URL that refers to either a trusted mirror site that's located reasonably close, or even to a private mirror site maintained by the organization that owns the high-security environment. Then the firewall administrators can minimize the length of the firewall access lists, which makes the security auditors happy.

The error message

```
Error: File contains no section headers.
file: file:///etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo, line: 4
'update status of each mirror to pick mirrors that are updated to and\n'
```

indicates there is something `yum` does not understand on line 4 of your `CentOS-Base.repo` file. And it even displays the contents of that line for you.

Compared to the example, it looks like someone may have removed the comment sign (the `#` character) from the beginning of the line. Since the rest of the line is just free-form text for humans to read, of course `yum` cannot make any sense of it.

Perhaps someone has tried to make modifications to the file with some sort of automated tool, and made a mistake, causing the tool to remove the comment signs from unintended locations?

You will have to view the contents of your `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` file and try and figure out what has happened. If the text lines at the beginning of the file have lost their comment marks, you should replace them or delete the free-form text lines.

Only the configuration sections, each starting with the square-bracketed section header line, have actual meaning for `yum`. If these have been lost or corrupted, you might have to either find an uncorrupted copy of the file from your backups, or Google for an example of that file for your specific version of CentOS and use it to fix your file. If you are working with high-security systems that are not allowed to make outgoing connections to basically any HTTP server over the internet, then you should find out how your systems are supposed to get their updates (a specific mirror you should use? internal mirror site? web proxy?) and adjust your rebuilt configuration accordingly.